# C# Bitmap Active Form > Object reference not set to an instance to an object

Tags: c#, bitmap

Im trying since few Days to solve the Error in my Screenshot Function of a Active Form...

`Object reference not set to an instance to an object`

My Problem: After few hours of running my exe, the Error show up (fresh start, it works without the Error)

What the Function does: open Form, Init new Chart, Fill it, Screenshot the Form and save the Screenshot...

Code >

```
                var frm = Form3.ActiveForm;
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                using (var bmp = new Bitmap(frm.Width, frm.Height))
                {
                    frm.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                    bmp.Save("TestX.png");
                }
```

Other Code, but not working to solve the Error

```
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        BringToFront();
```

The error is here > ... **(frm.Width, frm.Height)** Because the Form is not in the Front of all my other Applications and have no Width/Hight i think... If i then restart the exe, the Error is solved, and my Form is again in Front of all other Applications, and then after few Hours i have again the Problem...

Is there some Trick to solve it/or the Form must not in Front of all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because, at some point, your application ceases to have an active form, and the `Form3.ActiveForm` property returns `null` instead of a Form object. See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activeform?view=netframework-4.8)

I suggest you don't use `.ActiveForm` and instead do something else to determine the current form (i doubt it has to be active) - if this code is part of your form's codebehind then even `this` will work

```
using (var bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
```

If the code isn't in your form codebehind, you could pass an instance of your form to whatever helper class is creating the screenshot

```
ScreenshotHelper sh = new ScreenshotHelper(this); // assuming you create the helper as part of your form codebehind
```

Comment: Good Answer that i can Accept :) Thank You, looks that it works now :)